# Gramex-FormHandler-Filter-unique values of a column using url-param

Tags: gramex

[Gramex Form Handler: Filter](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-filters) doc sepcifies:
`Note: You can use FormHandler to render specific columns in navbar filters using ?_c=<data-column>.`

Also in the following section `You can specify custom aggregations using ?_c=col|<pandas-aggregation>`, but it only lists `count, min, avg, max` as the samples.

if I try with `?_c=<data-column>|unique` to get the list of unique values of any column? it's returning a list of empty-objects: `[{}, {},{} ...., {}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?_by=data_col&_c=data_col|unique` gives the result as a list: `[{"data_col":"val1","data_col|unique":["val1"]},{"data_col":"val2","data_col|unique":["val2"]}...]`

Comment: Can you explain this ?